# Swift project can not connect to internet through cellular

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm working on my final project, which need to get download some information from web server into my application and show it out.
It does work fine with wifi. However it doesn't work with cellular.
I've tried to head to Setting > Cellular and tried to turn on cellular option for my app but it was not there.
This is my first time posting the question, hope it's been clarified enough.
Thank you.

Comment: if your device available in wifi network? do you need to use Cellular ?

Comment: It is unlikely that cellular access is the problem. iOS hardly ever makes this distinction. More likely, your server is accessible from your WiFi (because it's in the same network), but shielded by a firewall when accessed from the outside (cellular). Please figure out the exact error message when downloading data and add it to your question.

Comment: whoop, sorry guys =D I was an idiot. The function used to check network connection was written by my group mate so I didn't check carefully. The function only check for wifi so that's why I had problem above =D
I fixed and its working fine with cellular now XD

Answer (score 0):

Every app when confirm the data connection and use it then start appearing in the section.Once it appears in this section you will able to remove it from there.

It means your app first need to use some cellular data.

Comment: `allowsCellularAccess ` is `true` by default. So this is unlikely to be the problem and/or the solution.

Comment: Does the cellular switch disable. not interaction in settings?

Comment: I turned the cellular on already :( I tried to find my app in cellular setting but couldnt find it

Comment: See the Edit. First setup your connection and make sure it works.

Answer (score 0):

whoop, sorry guys =D I was an idiot. The function used to check network connection was written by my group mate so I didn't check carefully. The function only check for wifi so that's why I had problem above =D I fixed and its working fine with cellular now XD